# Can I connect iPad to computer so I can use iPad as a keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, ipad

The computer keys seem to be stuck after coffee was spilt. Only a mouthful but that seems to have done it. The computer switches on all right, but the keyboard doesn't work.

Can I use my I pad as a keyboard until I can check out the problem on laptop as I need to print off from my laptop.

Comment: Make sure it is completely dry before switching on. Since you have switched it on, I would turn it off if I was not completely sure it was dry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few applications which can installed to use your iPad as a keyboard, however this requires the application to be installed on both the iPad and your PC (assuming you can't do this due to the keyboard not working).

I'd suggest leaving the laptop off until it's 100% COMPLETELY dry and obtaining a USB keyboard to use.

If you are still interested in applications to use with your iPad, here are a few:

1. http://www.airkeyboardapp.com/
2. http://www.remotemouse.net/
3. http://www.mobilemouse.com/ (Link given by @gparyani)

Please note, I have not used or tested the above applications.

Comment: Add http://mobilemouse.com/ to the list, too...

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes, you can use your iPad as a keyboard for your Mac or PC laptop.

Longer answer...

### Dry out the laptop first

As Xavierjazz mentioned in a comment, make sure the laptop is completely dry before you try to use it.

The only way to be sure it is completely dry is to completely dismantle the laptop, wipe up any moisture you see, and allow all the components to dry for several days.  If you do not dry it, moisture could remain in place or wick further into the laptop and cause permanent damage.  You can use a vacuum to suck air out of crevices or low-velocity airflow from a fan, but do NOT use high-velocity air such as compressed air (which can push moisture further into crevices).  Although rice is widely recommended for drying out electronics, more recent studies have debunked its ability as a desiccant.

### You might need to disconnect the built-in keyboard

If the keys are indeed stuck "on" then you may need to disconnect the laptop's keyboard cable from the motherboard in order to prevent the stuck keys from affecting the input from any other keyboard you try to use.  For example, if the laptop's Shift key is stuck "on" then anything you type on a different keyboard connected to the same laptop will be affected by the Shift key.

### USB keyboard or iPad as a keyboard

Once you've gotten past that hurdle, the simplest solution is to use an USB keyboard.  However, you can also use a remote desktop app such as [Splashtop](http://www.splashtop.com/personal), a keyboard app such as [Air Keyboard](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CFUQFjAC&url=https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/air-keyboard-remote-mouse/id446643462?mt=8&ei=haPdUo3OOKSW3AWOoYDICA&usg=AFQjCNGdJDXf_8K87fN31SVj56nKGjfZNA&bvm=bv.59568121,d.b2I), or any number of other apps that you can find by searching "ipad as keyboard" in Google.